# SQL to aggregate some variables as new variable "others" (SQLite)

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following table:

[image]

And I want to select **ONLY** A and D, and group persons B, C and E into a new variable called "others", like the table below:

[image]

How can I achieve that in SQLite?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `CASE`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN name IN ('Person A', 'Person D') THEN name
            ELSE 'Others'
       END AS name
       ,SUM(value) AS val
FROM tab
GROUP BY CASE WHEN name IN ('Person A', 'Person D') THEN name
              ELSE 'Others'
         END;
```

Comment: Works nicely. Thanks